# RMI Client and Server programms

Tags: java, rmi

I implemented a client and server programms using RMI. I wrote this both server and client classes in same project. But now I want to run this client and server programms separately (as two projects). So how can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Split your application into **three** artifacts/projects/JARs:

- `client` - code that calls the server via RMI API. Depends on `api`
- `server` - implement the API on the server side. Obviously `client` is not dependent on this artifact
- `api` - both `client` and `server` depend on API: `client` uses, `server` implements.

This approach allows you to develop both `client` and `server` independently. Also changing the `api` can't easily be missed since it is a separate project.

Answer (score -1):

You should have **main** method in each class you want to run. After creating main methods and compiling files, simply run each file, using your IDE or command "java". You don't need two projects to do this.